# How to increase resolution of gif image?

Tags: linux, r, gif, rgl

How to increase resolution of gif image generated by rgl package of R (plot3d and movie3d functions) - either externally or through R ?

R Code :

```
MyX<-rnorm(10,5,1)
MyY<-rnorm(10,5,1)
MyZ<-rnorm(10,5,1)
plot3d(MyX, MyY, MyZ, xlab="X", ylab="Y", zlab="Z", type="s", box=T, axes=F)
text3d(MyX, MyY, MyZ, text=c(1:10), cex=5, adj=1)
movie3d(spin3d(axis = c(0, 0, 1), rpm = 4), duration=15, movie="TestMovie",
                                                type="gif", dir=("~/Desktop"))
```

Output :

[image: Output]
**Update**

Adding this line at the beginning of code solved the problem

```
r3dDefaults$windowRect <- c(0, 100, 1400, 1400)
```

Comment: You mean you want to change  the width & height of the image? I ask because I am not sure to understand what you mean by resolution of an image. I use this term for my computer display..

Comment: Yes but without loosing quality. Tried [gifsicle](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/gifsicle.1.html). I loose quality with gifsicle

Comment: `movie3D` uses Image Magick. You can use the function's `convert` parameter to fine tune this. See the help file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do much about the resolution of the gif itself.  I think you have to make the image much larger as an alternative, and then when you display it smaller it looks better.  This is untested as a recent upgrade broke a thing or two for me, but this did work under 2.15:

```
par3d(windowRect = c(0, 0, 500, 500)) # make the window large
par3d(zoom = 1.1) # larger values make the image smaller

# you can test your settings interactively at this point

M <- par3d("userMatrix") # save your settings to pass to the movie

movie3d(par3dinterp(userMatrix=list(M,
    rotate3d(M, pi, 1, 0, 0), 
    rotate3d(M, pi, 0, 1, 0) ) ), 
    duration = 5, fps = 50,
    movie = "MyMovie")
```

HTH.  If it doesn't quite work for you, check out the functions used and tune up the settings.

Comment: I read about changing window size in R-help forum. Tried it. I get the following error (reported by others elsewhere, might be broken as you said): Error in par3d(windowRect = c(0, 0, 500, 500)) : 
  unknown error getting rgl parameter "windowRect". BTW I use R 2.12 and rgl 0.92.794

Comment: Are you on Mac or Windows?  On the Mac, there is a rogue file often left from earlier installs that causes these kinds of problems, and must be found and removed.  If you are on Mac, try googling your error and see if you can find the instructions (it's been a while since I fixed mine and don't quite remember - also check the main help archives).

Comment: I'm on Linux. Will check if updating packages will help. Thx

Comment: Check around... Macs run linux, so maybe the problem is the same.... See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878693/error-in-loading-rgl-package-with-mac-os-x But this looks very Mac specific, unless your system uses X11 windows.  You could also try building from source.

Comment: @BryanHanson you've opened up a flame war :-).  Macs do not run Linux -- they run Darwin, which is a Unix-based kernel.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I guess that's OK, it's 10 F here and we could use the heat!