# Installing "rgl" package in R, Mac OSX El Captian

Tags: r, macos, osx-elcapitan, rgl

I'm new to programming in R so I apologise in advance if I seem naive. I want to be able to do some principal components analysis on my data in 3D. I read that the "pca3d" function is good for this, but I need to download the "rgl" library. When I use install.packages it asks:

```
install.packages("rgl")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary    source needs_compilation
rgl 0.95.1201 0.95.1367              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: n
```

I have tried installing it as both binary and source, but nothing seems to work. If I try loading the binary version, I get this error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’
```

If I say "yes" to installing from source, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've been searching for hours on how to make this work so if someone could run through how I should go about installing the rgl package then I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks, 
Claire

Comment: As a start, the error message is saying that it looked for but could not find X11, so probably the first step is to install X11.

Comment: you can try to add as non-default parametr *repos* into install.packages function, so it will be like that: install.packages("rgl", repos='http ://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/')

**p.s.** sorry, but delete a space between *http* and *:* symbol

Answer (score 17):

After talking with a colleague all I had to do was download XQuartz from [here](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac) to install X11, and then install the source package again. Now it works!

Answer (score 4):

Downloading XQuartz completely solved everything after I wasted hours trying to come up with a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I first downloaded the package onto my desktop, but R gave me the same error, this is what worked for my Mac:

> install.packages("rgl", lib="Desktop/rgl_0.96.0 (1).tgz")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     'lib = "Desktop/rgl_0.96.0 (1).tgz"' is not writable
>   Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) 
>   y
>   Would you like to create a personal library
>   ~/Library/R/3.3/library
>   to install packages into?  (y/n) 
>   y

Answer (score 1):

In my case, not only install XQuartz but I need to also open XQuartz.app manually and then run install.packages("rgl").

Only by this way would R found X11 in my case...