# Rugarch Package on R don't load on mac laptop

Tags: r, macos, package

I am having problems loading `rugarch` package on `R` and I really need that package for my thesis.

I have no problem installing it. But when I try to load it I receive the following error message:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
>     Reason: image not found
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rugarch’

Any suggestions ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the package `rgl`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html
The error indicates that this package is needed.

Comment: @J_F I installed the package rgl and know I have this problem:
Loading required package: parallel
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so'

But there is a lot of packages with the name parallel

Comment: library(rgl)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  
> And this also happens to rgl package @J_F. So strange I cannot load these packages

Comment: Have you installed a c++ compiler for OSX? https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late but for other people searching for a solution. The solution that worked for me is to download and install XQuartz https://www.xquartz.org onto your Mac.

See Stackoverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551825/214332) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35328294/214332)