# rugarch will not load, but can install just fine (on mac)

Tags: r, installation-package

I am having trouble loading rugarch. I can install it no problem

```
install.packages('rugarch')
```

However, when I try to load it, I get errors

```
library(rugarch)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rugarch’
```

I have tried upgrading R, reinstalling the package both to no avail. Here is my system settings:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] foreach_1.4.2                 blotter_0.9.1666             
[3] FinancialInstrument_1.2.0     PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
[5] quantmod_0.4-5                TTR_0.23-0                   
[7] xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-12                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-14   lattice_0.20-33    mvtnorm_1.0-3      truncnorm_1.0-7   
 [5] grid_3.2.1         KernSmooth_2.23-15 misc3d_0.8-4       spd_2.0-1         
 [9] iterators_1.0.7    tools_3.2.1        numDeriv_2014.2-1  Rsolnp_1.15
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also I have tried to download it from the cran page but that gives the same error. For what its worth, rugarch will install and load on my windows computer running `3.2.0` 64-bit computer.

I tried to install an older version of rugarch from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rugarch/ but it wont even install. I tried `1.3-3, 1.3-1, and 1.2-9`. This is the error I get:

```
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.1.0
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rugarch/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rugarch’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rugarch’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Downloads/rugarch_1.2-9.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my R system.  I'm running `3.1.3` with `64-bit` Windows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it works on my windows computer running `3.2.0`, but not on my mac for some reason. I just edited my question to reflect this

Comment: I don't have a Linux box handy here.  The only thing I can recommend is that you try using an earlier version of `rugarch`.  Maybe the latest release has a bug which manifests on OSx.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The previous versions of `rugarch` wont even install. I tried `1.3-3, 1.3-1, and 1.2-9`. I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: Do you have `rgl` installed? If no, you need to install `xquartz` first, then `rgl`.

Comment: @Pascal thank you. That worked. I had rgl, but not xquartz, please change your comment to an answer.

Comment: Thanks to rawr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package#comment51566864_31820865

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late but for other people searching for a solution. The solution that worked for me

(as mentioned by user3710546 in the comments above)

is to download and install XQuartz https://www.xquartz.org

See Stackoverflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551825/214332) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35328294/214332)