# installing/accessing rgl package in mac yosemite

Tags: r, rgl

I am having problems with using rgl package after installing the rgal package. I am having a mac version 10.10.3 Yosemite installed and R studio of R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16). Let me know how I can install this correctly. I tried removing the rgl.so file by deleting but still the problem persists. Any thoughts?

```
 library(rgl)
 Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
 Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
 Reason: image not found
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact error message. After trying to install multiple previous versions both direct from CRAN url and via the command line I finally had success by updating `xquartz`.

Thanks to [rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package#comment51566864_31820865) via [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932943/rugarch-will-not-load-but-can-install-just-fine-on-mac#comment51777856_31932943)!